# Convert list to TreeMap in Map

Tags: scala

I have a list of map with record like this

```
List(Map(id => 123, Date => 2020.04.01, Value => abc),
     Map(id => 123, Date => 2020.04.03, Value => def),
     Map(id => 456, Date => 2020.04.04, Value => eee),
     Map(id => 456, Date => 2020.04.02, Value => bcd))
```

And I would like to convert that to something like below for further processing:

```
Map(id => 123, TreeMap(Date=>2020.04.01, Value => abc; Date=>2020.04.03, Value => def);
    id => 456, TreeMap(Date=>2020.04.02, Value => bcd; Date=>2020.04.04, Value => eee))
```

I have below code to do that:

```
val result = mutable.Map[String, mutable.TreeMap[String, String]]();
list.foreach(m => {
  val id = m("id")
  if (!result.contains(id))
    result += id -> mutable.TreeMap.empty[String, String]
  result(id) += m("date") -> m("value")
})
```

Just wonder if there are some clever way to do that? I know there is toMap() method but not sure how to initalize TreeMap inside toMap method.

Comment: `TreeMap` in your example contains duplicate keys.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your `result` code is correct, here's the same thing in an FP (immutable) manner.

```
import scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap

List(Map("id" -> "123", "Date" -> "2020.04.01", "Value" -> "abc")
    ,Map("id" -> "123", "Date" -> "2020.04.03", "Value" -> "def")
    ,Map("id" -> "456", "Date" -> "2020.04.04", "Value" -> "eee")
    ,Map("id" -> "456", "Date" -> "2020.04.02", "Value" -> "bcd"))
  .foldLeft(Map.empty[String,TreeMap[String,String]]
               .withDefaultValue(TreeMap.empty[String,String])){
    case (acc, m) => 
      val id = m("id")
      acc + (id -> (acc(id) + (m("Date") -> m("Value"))))
  }

//val res0: immutable.Map[String,TreeMap[String,String]] = 
//   Map(123 -> TreeMap(2020.04.01 -> abc, 2020.04.03 -> def)
//     , 456 -> TreeMap(2020.04.02 -> bcd, 2020.04.04 -> eee))
```

Comment: `withDefault` can a cause surprising results since that default is preserved after the `foldLeft`. I would use `updatedWith` in the body of the `foldLeft`.